# TinyMCE add clickable button/div inside editor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, editor

I would like to add a clickable button/image/div inside the html editor (not the navigation bar). But when I use the onBeforeSetContent.add function to filter content and add an element with an **onclick** tag, this tag gets stripped.

This is all done via a tinymce plugin btw since I'm using Wordpress.

```
//replace shortcode before editor content set
ed.onBeforeSetContent.add(function(ed, o) {
    o.content = t.filter_content(o.content);
});
```

...

```
filter_content : function(co) {
    return co.replace(/\[icitspot([^\]]*)\]/g, function(a,b){
        return '<img src="#" onclick="alert(\'abc\')" class="wpSpot mceItem" title="clickme" />';
    });
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the onclick attribute, click events should be detected in general:

```
ed.onClick.add(function(ed, e) {
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

Now you can detect the element that was clicked and determine if it's your button/div.

Answer (score 1):

Either use your own solution or you will have to specify `onclick` as a valid attribute to prevent the stipping of this attribute using the tinymce [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration:valid_elements) setting.

Example:

```
valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style|onmouseover|onclick]," +
"a[name|href|target|title|alt]," +
"#p,blockquote,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src|height|width],-sub,-sup,-b,-i,-u," +
"-span[data-mce-type],hr",
```